# Simultaneously retrieving multiple data using $q in angular

Tags: angularjs

Folks ..

I need to retrieve data from around 8 difference resources when my program begins.

These resources are independent of each other can can be called parallelly. (i.e I don't need data from one to determine what to retrieve from another resource)

However anything ahead needs to ensure that I have all the data from all the resources on-hand since they operate on each other.

So at the beginning of my controller I call a init function with the following code :

***EDIT** To be more specific my exact code is as below

```
$scope.init = function () {
    return $q.all([
    Factory1.getCarData.query(), // returns a resource object like [$resolved: false, $then: function]
    Factory2.getOtherData.query(), // returns a resource object like [$resolved: false, $then: function] 
    Factory3.getSomeOtherData.query() // returns a resource object like [$resolved: false, $then: function]
    ....,
    resource8.query()]).then(result) {
        $scope.data1 = result[1];
        $scope.data2 = result1[2];...
        $scope.data8 = result[3];

        console.log($scope.data1); //prints as [$resolved: false, $then: function]
        console.log($scope.data1[1]);
        prints as undefined

        doSomethingonData1($scope.data2);
        doSomethingonData2($scope.data3, $scope.data4);..etc etc
    }
}
```

Where Factory1 is defined as :

```
angular.module('app').factory('Factory1', function (Factory1Resource)  {    
   var carPromise = Factory1Resource.query(); 
    return {
      getCarData: function(){ return carPromise;}
    }
```

and Factory1Resource is defined as :

```
.factory('Factory1Resource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource(myURL, {}, {} );
  }])
```

The whole point of using the factories is to ensure that the data manipulation for all 8 resources is done outside the controller in a indiviual units.

My point is .. I thought that the ".then" function would be invoked only once all resources have resolved. which means that my variables $scope.data1, $scope.data2 etc should have the actual data and not be resource objects.

This is not the case as when I do console.log($scope.data1) .. it prints as [$resolved: false, $then: function]

This breaks the flow of my program.

Now I thought I had done a lot of reading on promises and resources and I was now a enlightened person but apparently i am missing something here.

What I want is that my variables ($scope.data1, $scope.data2 etc) all contain actual data.

Any hints ? Alternately feel free to suggest any better ideas you may have as to how I should lay out my code.

Answer (score 0):

`then()` takes a function, do it like this

```
.then(function(result) {
    $scope.data1 = result[1];
    ...
});
```

Created a demo for you and I simplified a bit of your code. It works fine. <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SrpG8/)**</kbd>

Comment: That's exactly how it is.. my typo..else I would get syntax error

Comment: @JamesHans OK. You post your code with so many typos and this can only confuses everyone here who wants to help you. Can you fix it? And what is `result1`?

Comment: @JamesHans http://jsfiddle.net/SrpG8/ Created a demo for you and I simplified a bit of your code. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

@sza thank you so much for the advice and help here. This does seem the right way to do it however to have a fool proof system in place I did the below :

Set flags in the `".then"` section of all `Factory.getData.query()` - so now code looks like:

```
Factory1.getCarData.query().then(function(){Data1Retrieved == true})
```

After this, I keep a watch on all flags, once all flags turn true I start rest of the processing. Again I don't know if this is the right way to do it but it sure seems to be effective.

Thank you everyone for your input again.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing the object returned by `resource.query` directly to `$q.all(` you should pass `resource.query().$promise`.

According to angular $resource documentation

> The Resource instances and collection have these additional
>   properties:
>
> $promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created
>   this instance or collection.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

**update**

I decided to create a test by myself using an existing app I developed. I'm going to paste the code that worked for me. Maybe you have a different structure when you're calling the resources:

```
 $provide.factory('GenericResource', ['$resource','$q', function($resource,$q){
        var AccountResource = $resource('/user/accounts/balances'),
            BankResource = $resource('/banks');

        $q.all([AccountResource.query().$promise, BankResource.query().$promise]).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }]);
```

What output of console.log is:

```
[
Array[3]
    0: Resource
    1: Resource
    2: Resource
    $promise: Object
    $resolved: true
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array[0]
, 
    Array[4]
    0: Resource
    1: Resource
    2: Resource
    3: Resource
    $promise: Object
    $resolved: true
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array[0]
]
```

As you can see the the data returned contained 3 and 4 resource objects representing the data fetched. Is this result similar to the one of yours?

Comment: on using somthing like :  resource1.query().$promse  .. it still goes into the "then" part without resolving. If I print console.log($scope.data1) in ".then" I get undefined

Comment: @JamesHans How about if you just print `result`?

Comment: @enr.code  .. our code is very close..I have made edits.. pls see above

Comment: You're not returning the promise in this segment of your code... 
   `var carPromise = Factory1Resource.query(); 
    return {
      getCarData: function(){ return carPromise}
    }`

try doing `var carPromise = Factory1Resource.query().$promise;`

Comment: when I do that Factory1Resource.query().$promise the data never gets updated in the controller for some strange reason. i.e result never gets populated with a value.

Comment: You should check your web services then. Also check what's inside `result` array. The only way to make $q.all() work is by passing the `$promise` object.